# How to download non-DRM version of game from Steam to run in WINE?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, macos, wine, drm

I just purchased a turn-based game which is only supported on Windows (it’s [*Cogmind*](http://store.steampowered.com/app/722730/Cogmind/), if relevant). Since I’m on macOS, the game won’t download when I click “Install Game...”:

> An error occurred while updating Cogmind: Invalid platform

While this game doesn’t officially support my operating system, its community has figured out [a way to run it through Wine](http://www.gridsagegames.com/forums/index.php?topic=29.msg405#msg405). Also, it’s worth-noting that running the game this way is actually [encouraged by the developer](http://www.gridsagegames.com/cogmind/faq.html).

Is it possible to download the non-DRM version of the game with the Steam client?

Comment: If the developer encourages it, then the developer should also know how to achieve it. Makes logical sense to ask them.

Comment: @Flater The developer also sales a DRM-free version of this game on their own website, and I guess this is how the community get it run on Linux/macOS.

Comment: You should still contact the developer. Your Steam version still has a license key (and code) attached to it, which means that the developer may be able to give you access to the DRM-free version on his website based on that key. Rimworld (early access) took a similar approach to making both versions accessible for everyone.

Comment: Also, I believe GOG had a program earlier this year where you could link it to your Steam account, and if you'd purchased anything on Steam that a) also existed on GOG and b) was part of this program, you'd get the DRM-free GOG version added to your account for free. I believe I used this to get _FTL: Faster Than Light_ on GOG after I'd already purchased it on Steam

Comment: You could try to install the Windows Steam on Wine. I don't know but I've heard rumors that works.

Comment: This is also a candidate for 'ethical' cracking whereby you're gaining access to a game you already own.

Comment: Not all games on Steam have DRM. Have you tried just copypasting the game folder from Steam to your linux installation and running it through Wine?

Comment: @AdamV I think GOG discontinued that program. The current program they were offering was the get a DRM free edition of old games you have a disk and serial code for.

Comment: @bp. that's exactly what I proposed [in my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/321706/66556), because it's mostly parallel to the unlocking DRM/copy-protection of medium-protected games for backup/compatibility reasons - just to get an instant downvote and a delete vote. I fail how saying "you can crack it if you consider it's legal for you" is not useful by itself, but perhaps I'm not up-to-date on current status of DRM-related [chilling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilling_effect) on SE network...

Comment: @jskrwyk [the program is not discontinued](https://www.gog.com/connect), but the available games are always cycling, so make sure you check back every now and then.

Comment: @Chippies While the page still exists you can see there are no games that are currently part of the program, and it’s been that way for a fair while now. Discontinued may be the wrong word but I️ wouldn’t say it’s an active offer.

Comment: @jskrwyk from what I can tell, there is no list (at least on that page) that show all games that are part of the program, it only shows the games that *you own on steam* that are part of the program. If you already have claimed the games that are part of the program and haven't bought any new ones, it will show as empty.

Comment: @Chippies Thats interesting. When they first launched it it did show a list on the page in that block that now says “More coming soon” even without your account connected but they could have changed the UI design flow.

Comment: @jskrwyk I believe it showed the games only until you redeemed them. Once you had them in your library and refreshed the page, I am fairly certain they were gone from the page. That being said - I could be remembering wrong...

Comment: I redeemed some games in June 2017.  It cycles out and the window is relatively short.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Steam is a DRM enforcing client.  It doesn't provide a version of software that is not DRM restricted.

However, you can install Steam on WINE itself.  It will then detect it is on a "Windows platform" and install the game.

Comment: You're fully correct, but do note that some Steam games have no inherent DRM (in the sense that you can copy the files and run them in a separate instance, away from the Steam install directory). This is (or at least used to be) the case for Kerbal Space Program, Rimworld and Factorio.

Comment: @Flater [here's a list of them](http://steam.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_DRM-free_games)

Answer (score 3):

For some games you can just copy files, but some require Steam for at least some functionality (friend list, server list etc.)

Cogmind uses SteamCloud to backup your saved games and for global High Scores list.

Also, Steam detects WINE as WINE, not as Windows. They specifically made it to also count users on MacOS/Linux who use WINE.

You should run Steam on WINE instead. That way there are less things that can go wrong, and better chances that everything works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to download the non-DRM version of the game with the Steam client?

Define what you understand by "non-DRM'. If a game is *inherently* DRM-free (see [here](http://steam.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_DRM-free_games)), you *can* download the DRM-free version from Steam; it will be put into your `steamapps/common` dir - you can copy/move it out of there if you wish (note the possible caveats).

If the game *is* DRM-protected *and* the license allows for DRM-free use of the game *or* you don't care about fine legal aspects of the situation and just want to play **the game you already bought** (again, caveats), you *may* (with very high likelihood) succeed by using a cracked `steam_api.dll` or its derivatives/substitutes. I won't provide the exact links for the obvious reasons (a quick Google search for e.g. "how to crack steam MPGH" or "steam emulator" can lead your way), but the generic `steam_api` crack allows to use many (if not most) games in a DRM-free way. Note that you *will* have the *exact* Steam version of the game (updates, virus-free etc.), but you *won't* have access to Steam-related features (friends, achievements etc.); it's arguable whether this can be called "DRM-free version", but it most certainly will be *downloaded from Steam*.

Alternatively, just [use](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Wine) your [Steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777115/running-windows-steam-on-linux-using-wine) on [WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444). (caveats, yet again!)

NOTE: I **don't** condone piracy (copyright abuse/software theft) in any way. I, however, argue that a user *has the right* to break *licensing* terms (EULA) of the software *he can legally use* (bought/paid for or received free of charge) if they are *exceedingly* prohibitive (because that is the usual court ruling in such cases, both in EU and some US states) - the worst legal implication here is that the license may get revoked by the issuer (in this case, you may *legally* get banned from Steam for circumventing its protection). I assume that's a call everyone should consider by themselves.

Comment: We don't support piracy in *any* sense.  Please don't answer with solutions that advocate such.

Comment: @Frank are you aware of the distinction between [*piracy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement) and [*cracking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_cracking)? From your statement, I assume you don't. I never mentioned *pirating* software; to download it from Steam you essentially *have* to have it bought already. How is downloading a game you already own "piracy"?
 Also, quote from Wikipedia: "It might be legal to use cracked software in certain circumstances.". I never said it *is* legal.

Comment: Yes, cracking is legal in *some* cases.  In the absolute *vast* majority, it most definitely is **not**.  Especially when it comes to fooling Steam, which *is* illegal.  Bypassing DRM is explicitly forbidden in the DMCA, so for Arqade, we provide zero support for piracy, or allow answers that support doing so.

Comment: @Frank IMVHO you're wrong as to DMCA: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/07/court-breaking-drm-for-a-fair-use-is-legal/ ; it was and is controversial as whether personal removal of DRM that's been placed in a way that restricts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implied_warranty of fitness for an explicit purpose of the merchandise is legal or not. DMCA only holds as long as it breaks no other law; if it makes the product impossible to use in a normal way, it's the seller who's doing so behaving illegally, not the buyer who tries to get what he paid for.

Comment: @Frank as to Steam itself: while G. Restrictions on Use of Content and Services say that "You may not use [it] for any purpose other than the permitted access to Steam (...) and to make personal, non-commercial use of your Subscriptions (...) you may not, in whole or in part (long list here) " - but see Sec. 103(f) of the DMCA. Connect the dots. Arguably, the "interoperatibility" it speaks of can be clearly applied to this case (reverse-engineering Steam's protocol and using a drop-in replacement to use a software you legally obtained in a way that expresses it's purpose).

Comment: @Frank apart from that, *I never expressed any support for piracy*. Unless you provide me with the exact definition of "piracy" you use, I can't agree with you, because your argument is a clear case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man

Comment: If you really want to debate law, I'd suggest posting a Meta article about it.  My understanding is that circumventing DRM was taken off the list of allowable exceptions the last time the exceptions came up for renewal.  Either way, our stance is not to support piracy in any sense, so a distinction in this area would be a good thing.  The way I see it, providing methods to circumvent protection is piracy, and I doubt I'm the only one to see it that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68989/discussion-between-vaxquis-and-frank).

Comment: This answer is tangential to the question.  The OP's interest was for the game to install on a Mac, and thought he needed to somehow get a copy of the game to run in WINE.  Steam has support for WINE and that's the real solution: install Steam in WINE.  Once that's done, there's no point of looking into bypassing anything.

Comment: @Nelson I agree that that's one of the ways to approach the problem. However, (I assume you're a WINE user and you know the fact) WINE known for causing problems with DRM, since some of them (SecuROM e.g.) doesn't work too well with WINE. How is that "tangential" then?

Comment: I want to point out that the point about DMCA is very US-centric. EU courts have been generally much more forgiving against circumventing DRM when it is used to limit what the user can do. It's not because US laws sucks that you have to force everyone into following them.